# Setup Galera Cluster with two servers

Tags: apache-2.2, cluster, high-availability, galera

Can I Create Gallera Cluster with two servers ??

Actually I have 6 servers:

2 Server for Load Balancer
2 Server for Apache

Or anyone here can suggest me how to create High Availability Web Server with 6 servers?

Thanks

Comment: Please try to do your home work and read the [vendor documentation](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/gettingstarted.html#system-requirements) - Second please to try to confine your questions a single question or at least to a single topic, because that makes answering them easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. This is called a 2 + 1 set-up. 2 Galera nodes + 1 Galera arbitrator sitting on one of the app-server nodes.
But it is NOT a recommended set-up.

An alternative would be to put the Load Balancer on the app-servers. Then you have 3 db nodes and 3 app servers. But from the maintenance point of view this is more work than 2 central load balancers.

Regards,
Oli